# Infinite resistor problem from a graph theory standpoint

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to understand the infinite grid of resistors problem from a graph theory stand point(classic xkcd/google problem). Since effective resistance is the same as the commute time,  this is really asking with the expected number of steps it will take to walk from point a on the grid to point b and back(multiplied by some constants which are not important here).

Now I am aware of the result that says that on an infinite grid, as the time goes toward infinity, the probability that you reach any particular point is 1. However, reading(https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-expected-number-of-steps-to-reach-the-starting-position-again-in-a-2-dimensional-random-walk) convinces me that the expected number of steps is also infinite. This means that the effective resistance between any two points should effectively be zero. However, this does not seem to be the accepted solution.

Please help me see where my logic is breaking down.

Regards,
Pericles

Comment: There is a problem: the resistance goes *up* with the length of the paths to get there but it goes *down* with the variety of paths available. Because there are infinitely many paths available (even when you prohibit backtracking), you get a subtle difficulty.

Comment: Are you saying that the relationship between commute time and resistance doesn't hold for infinite graphs?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you mean by commute time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement that "effective resistance is the same as commute time... multiplied by some constants which are not important here" is wrong. In fact the exact theorem is found here: [“The electrical resistance of a graph captures its commute and cover times” - A. Chandra, P. Raghavan, W. Ruzzo, R. Smolensky, and P. Tiwari.](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~ruzzo/papers/resist.pdf) , which says that:

$$C(a,b)=2mR(a,b),$$

where $C(a,b)$ is the commute time between vertices $a,b$; $R(a,b)$ is the effective resistance and $m$ is the number of edges in the graph. In the case of an infinite grid, $m=\infty$.

Comment: I see. Yes you are correct that that is where the problem is. I wonder if there is still a way to solve this problem by considering the convergence of C(a,b)/m.